# Unable to update file in the Google Drive by using resumable approach

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api

I've been trying to learn how to use the Google Drive API to update a file in the Google Drive by using a resumable session.

*I received a 'Forbidden' response to the upload content request.*

Could you help me find missing or misused steps?

1. User is authorized with permissions:

   - drive.file (https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file)
2. Execute a request to create resumable session:

   PATCH 'https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files/1XIU63B-U8b9Fe1_UFFVvd7OOdS_ANqAj?uploadType=resumable
3. Retrieve session url:

   https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files/1XIU63B-U8b9Fe1_UFFVvd7OOdS_ANqAj?uploadType=resumable&upload_id=AEnB2Uqew...
4. Send content by using  resumable session:

   PUT https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files/1XIU63B-U8b9Fe1_UFFVvd7OOdS_ANqAj?uploadType=resumable&upload_id=AEnB2Uqew...

   I didn't find anything specific related to this step in the documentation, so I use regular upload documentation https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-uploads#upload-resumable to update file in "Multiple chunks"
5. I get **403 error** status code with 'Forbidden' reason and header with upload_id:

   X-GUploader-UploadID: AEnB2Uqewr...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You want to update the existing file in Google Drive with the resumable upload method.

Unfortunately, from your question, I couldn't understand about the detail request body of your test. By this, I cannot replicate your situation. So in this answer, I would like to propose a sample flow for updating the existing file with the resumable upload.

### Sample situation:

In this answer, as a sample situation, it supposes that a text file in Google Drive is updated by the resumable upload with the multiple chunks. And as the method for requesting, I use the curl command.

I prepared 2 files for 2 chunks. As the test situation, the 2 chuncs of 262,144 bytes and 37,856 bytes are uploaded. So total upload size is 300,000 bytes.

When you use the resumable upload, please be careful the following point.

> Add the chunk's data to the request body. Create chunks in multiples of 256 KB (256 x 1024 bytes) in size, except for the final chunk that completes the upload. Keep the chunk size as large as possible so that the upload is efficient. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-uploads#upload-resumable)

### Flow for updating a file with the resumable upload:

#### 1. Initiate a resumable upload session

Create the session for uploading with the resumable upload. In this case, the existing file is updated, so the endpoint is `PUT https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files/[FILE_ID]?uploadType=resumable`. But as an important point, please use the method of `PATCH` instead of `PUT`. When `PUT` is used, `location` is not included in the response header. I thought that the official document might be not correct.

```
$ curl -X PATCH -i \
  -H "Authorization: Bearer ###accessToken###" \
  "https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files/[FILE_ID]?uploadType=resumable"
```

If you want to update the file as the multipart upload, please use the following sample command. In this case, the filename is changed.

```
$ curl -X PATCH -i \
  -H "Authorization: Bearer ###accessToken###" \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8" \
  -d '{"name":"updatedFilename.txt"}' \
  "https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files/[FILE_ID]?uploadType=resumable"
```

- When above sample command is run, `200 OK` is returned, and the response header includes `location` like `location: https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files/[FILE_ID]?uploadType=resumable&upload_id=###`. For uploading the data, `location` is used as the endpoint.

#### 2. Upload the 1st chunk

```
$ curl -X PUT -i \
  -H "Content-Length: 262144" \
  -H "Content-Range: bytes 0-262143/300000" \
  -H "Content-Type: text/plain" \
  -F "file=@data1.txt" \
  "https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files/[FILE_ID]?uploadType=resumable&upload_id=###"
```

- When this curl command is run, `308 Resume Incomplete` is returned. By this, it is found that the chunk could be correctly uploaded.

#### 3. Upload the 2nd chunk (This is the last chunk of this sample flow.)

```
$ curl -X PUT -i \
  -H "Content-Length: 37856" \
  -H "Content-Range: bytes 262144-299999/300000" \
  -H "Content-Type: text/plain" \
  -F "file=@data2.txt" \
  "https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files/[FILE_ID]?uploadType=resumable&upload_id=###"
```

- When this curl command is run, `200 OK` is returned, and the file metadata is also returned. By this, it is found that the resumable upload could be correctly done.

### Note:

- **In this case, the file is updated as the overwrite. So please be careful this.**
- In my environment, even when `PUT` is modified to `PATCH` for uploading the chunks, I could confirm that the above flow worked.

  - If in your environment, an error occurs, please try to test this modification.
- About above sample situation, if you want to upload one chunk of 300,000 bytes, please use `-H "Content-Length: 300000" -H "Content-Range: bytes 0-299999/300000"`.

### References:

- [Perform a resumable upload](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-uploads#resumable)

Comment: Thanks for the extended answer, this helped me understand that I was using the correct flow, and the actual problem should be with the request to send the content. I reproduced it: “The parents field is not writable directly in update requests. Use the addParents and removeParents options instead. ” So, I just need to remove the “parents” from the file metadata during update operation.

Comment: @Pavel Thank you for replying and testing it. I'm glad your issue was resolved.Thank you, too.

Comment: @Tanaike, If the chunks are not in multiple of 256KB what could be a possible solution there?

Comment: anyway you could do this in C#?  I have been having issues with this for sometime and just can't crack it- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71594304/why-is-my-updatefile-getting-a-null-in-the-response-in-google-drive-api-v3-using